# Embedding SL app in another SL app and isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

Is it possible to dynamically embed a third-party Silverlight app in your own SL app? If so, would the former have access to the latter's isolated storage? Or would it have its own iso store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly download and execute DLLs from XAP files (which are only ZIP files)  dynamically as that is how PRISM and other modular Silverlight systems work.

When you ran the third-party app it would complain that you had already defined the root element for the visual tree. You will need to sort that out first.

If you can avoid the other problems, I am guessing the ISO storage will likely be that of the parent application as the third-party app has been loaded into its app domain equivalent.

### Update

Based on your comments below, you want to use it *downloaded from another site*. That will only work of the site has a clientaccesspolicy.xml that allows you to get at the file in the first place.

### Summary

Silverlight apps are generally not designed to be consumed by other Silverlight apps. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you would be better off obtaining the components you require and putting them in your own app.

Comment: I was thinking of adding the third party app as a children of my root Grid. The external app should be implemented as a UserControl.

Comment: This is what I recently found: "The identity of a Silverlight application is the full URL to the Silverlight application's XAP file. For example, http://microsoft.com/app.xap is the application identity of a Silverlight application hosted at http://microsoft.com/app.xap"

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't support multiple app domains, so if you load dll (silverlight app is nothing more than dll) into your sliverlight app it will have same access rights as your own code. That includes access to the isolated storage, also if your app have elevated permissions then loaded dll will have elevated permission as well. You should consider very carefully the repercussions of loading untrusted 3rd party dlls into your app as it could result in the serious security breach.